# Session Timeout in Google App Engine Struts 2

Tags: google-app-engine, struts2, session-timeout

What is the default session timeout in Google App Engine? How to set the session timeout in Google App Engine, in Struts 2 application. Any reference/docs on session in GAE? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Session Timeout setting should be done in a standard way via the `web.xml` and App Engine would ideally acknowledge it.

For e.g.

```
<session-config>
      <session-timeout>30</session-timeout> 
</session-config>
```

This will set the timeout to 30 minutes.